# Setting ImageSource to path outside application package

Tags: c#, image, win-universal-app, imagesource

How can I change an ImageSource that's outside the application package? I'm using this:

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (file != null)
{
    grid.Background = new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Absolute))
    };
}
```

But, after I pick the image I want, it just doesn't show as the grid background. It shows nothing! Here's the XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="315,260,85,140" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0" Visibility="Visible">
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file first:

```
if (file != null)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

    var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

    var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

    grid.Background = new ImageBrush
    {

        ImageSource = bitmapImage
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help!